# How to show sub items in wordpress custom navigation

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have been searching about how I can add php to my custom menu so that it shows the sub heading in a drop down fashion. 
I have created a custom menu using some php code as I wanted to have the logo situated in the middle of the navigation. The current php code looks like this:

```
<div class="navigation">
<ul>
    <?php
        $menu_left = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 3 );
        $menu_right = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 4 );

        foreach ( (array) $menu_left as $key => $menu_item ) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"" . $menu_item->url . "\">" . $menu_item->title . "</a></li>" ;

        }

    ?>
    <?php
        echo "<li><img src='logo1.png'/></li>";
    ?>
    <?php
        foreach ( (array) $menu_right as $key => $menu_item ) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"" . $menu_item->url . "\">" . $menu_item->title . "</a></li>" ;
    }  
    ?>
</ul>

</div><!-- .navigation -->
```

This is in my functions file:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
'nav_left' => 'Left Nav Menu',
'nav_right' => 'Right Nav Menu',
 ) );
```

The sub items that I have added through the menu in wordpress show up but they do not show underneath their parent page. I am relatively new to php and have been struggling with this for a while now. I am just not sure how to get them to display under the parent. I understand that the sub menu needs to be a new ul but I don't know how i Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for that I managed to get it to work using this

```
$menu_left = wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=0&sort_column=menu_order&exclude=56&number=8&exclude=13,15,17');( 3 );
        $menu_right = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 4 );
        foreach ( (array) $menu_left as $key => $menu_item ) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"" . $menu_item->url . "\">" . $menu_item->title . "</a></li>" ;
        }
```

I added all the menu items in the custom menu and then excluded the particular page id tags and it is working fine so thanks again! I hope this helps anyone else having some issues.

I found this site very useful and interesting: http://digwp.com/2009/07/delicious-recipes-wordpress-page-menus/

Answer (score 0):

For two Level Navigation Menu

```
wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'top_nav_menu', 
'container' => '',
'depth' => 2 ,
'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) 
);
```